# cannot set up PAT authentication for git on linux server via rstudio

Tags: r, linux, git, authentication, rstudio

I have access to a Linux server at work where I code in RStudio. Recently, the pull/push buttons have been greyed out in the git pane, and I also haven't updated from basic password authentication which I know GitHub is deprecating soon. However, I can't get it to accept a PAT, and clearly this repository has gotten unlinked from GitHub somehow.

When I run `git remote -v` from the terminal, I see the correct repository and branches.

When I run `gitcreds::gitcreds_set()` from R, it shows my correct GH username, and that it has saved a password. It then gives me an option to replace the credentials, but when I put in a new PAT (shown below as XXXXXX), I get an error:

```
-> What would you like to do? 

1: Keep these credentials
2: Replace these credentials
3: See the password / token

Selection: 2

-> Removing current credentials...

? Enter new password or token: XXXXXXXX
Error in new_git_error("git_error", args = args, stdout = out, status = attr(out,  : 
  System git failed: error: unknown option `get-urlmatch'
usage: git config [options]
```

I tried googling this error but haven't come across anything useful. Thanks in advance for any ideas. I imagine that fixing the git connection will also fix the greyed-out push/pull buttons in RStudio.

Comment: `--get-urlmatch` was new in Git 1.8.5. This is a very old version of Git, at this point, but some distributions (*cough* centos *cough*) come with even-older versions of Git. What version of Git is installed on your system?

Comment: AHA. It's on 1.8.3.1. Is there a way to switch to PAT authentication using commands that ancient git will recognize, or do I have to convince our sysadmin to update git?

Comment: You could probably just install a newer Git for personal use, but in general installing a newer Git is a good thing all around. I don't know how the `--get-urlmatch` option is being used so I don't know how to convert the RStudio call.

Comment: Yup, I asked for git to be updated and it worked immediately after that. Thanks! Could you post this as the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--get-urlmatch` option to `git config` first appeared in Git version 1.8.5.  While any modern Linux system will ship with a Git version of at least 2.0, there are a bunch of rather old systems that still come with Git 1.8 or even 1.7 variants.

There might be a way to work around this in RStudio, but your best bet is probably to get a newer Git version installed on the system.  Git is generally pretty backwards-compatible although there were a few user-interface-default changes between 1.x and 2.0 (and there's another one coming up, though I doubt anyone will call this 3.0).